# Generate Excel sheet from a list of hash maps

Tags: java, excel, java-8, hashmap, apache-poi

I have a list of two hash maps with the same set of keys but different values.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("t1", "val1");
map1.put("t2", "val2");
map1.put("t3", "val3");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("t1", "str1");
map2.put("t2", "str2");
map2.put("t3", "str3");
```

I want to generate an excel sheet such that the keys will be in the header row, and all values will come under it as below:

```
t1     t2   t3
val1   val2 val3
str1   str2 str3
```

Can anyone suggest a way out of it?

Comment: Too broad (needs details or clarity, includes multiple questions). Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: [_How do I efficiently iterate over each entry in a Java Map?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46898/230513) or [_How do I write a spreadsheet?_](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bapache-poi%5d%20write%20spreadsheet)